# Gatsby - TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript, gatsby

In my Gatsby site I get the following error: TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null.

I tried the solutions from other stackoverflow questions related to this one. But none seems to work on a Gatsby site. I also don't know how I can implement my Javascript code in the footer with Gatsby.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("OffcanvasNav").style.left = "0"
        document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("closeNav").style.display = "initial"
    }

    document.getElementById("openNav").onclick = openNav

    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("OffcanvasNav").style.left = "100%"
        document.getElementById("closeNav").style.display = "none"
        document.getElementById("openNav").style.display = "initial"
    }

    document.getElementById("closeNav").onclick = closeNav
});

document.getElementById("openNav").onclick = openNav should open my offcanvas navbar.

document.getElementById("closeNav").onclick = closeNav should clode my offcanvas navbar.
```

Comment: I think we need more info here. Where is your html structure coming from? React components or something else?

Comment: The code you have here doesn't look entirely compatible with a React application. Any redraw could potentially remove these event listeners, hence them not working.

Comment: Also, your last two lines of code are selecting the `#openNav` and `#closeNav` elements as soon as the script is loaded. Depending on where are you placing that script it may be possible that the elements are still not present in the DOM.